# Какой принцип в пунктуации является основным?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, семантика, правила, интонация

Этот вопрос адресован участникам, которым интересна не только практика, но и теория письма.

**1.  Какой принцип главнее и насколько правильны наши правила**

Русская пунктуация основана **на трех принципах** – смысловом, грамматическом и интонационном. А какой из них главный? Эта тема подробно излагается у Валгиной в книге «Актуальные проблемы современной пунктуации» (2004 год).

И сразу мне попадается **интересная информация**.

**С точки зрения назначения пунктуации** (вероятно, с точки зрения истины), главным является **семантический принцип**, а выделять отдельные принципы можно только условно, так они образуют «триединство».

**«С точки зрения основ пунктуации**, грамматический принцип является основным, так как большая часть правил опирается именно на него…Можно с уверенностью сказать, что **грамматический принцип является сейчас ведущим,** тогда как принципы смысловой и интонационный выступают в качестве хотя и обязательно действующих, но дополнительных».

Что же это получается, наши правила не соответствуют действительным отношениям? Хороши же правила, где смыслу отведено такое скромное место!

**2.  Можно ли разделить неделимые принципы**

Можно как-то разделить эти неделимые принципы (это всё-таки не «атом неделимый»), а также  построить **систему взаимоотношений** между разными  понятиями в этой теме?

Вот если у вас спросят, **что лучше, машина или катер**, то вы, вероятно, удивитесь. На реке лучше катер, а на дороге машина, как их можно сравнивать? Они оба служат для передвижения, но каждый  предмет в своей среде. В таком же соответствии находятся **знаки препинания и интонация**: между ними есть **соответствие**, но знаки ставятся на письме, а интонация характеризует устную речь.

**Содержание и форма** – это две основные философские категории. Но вот только речь имеет две формы – грамматическую и фонетическую.

Содержание выражается грамматической формой, а **знаки препинания** (на письме) могут **уточнять** и дополнять грамматическую форму, если это требуется.

К примеру, нам нужно выразить однородные отношения между определениями, но  основная грамматическая форма с этим не справляется.  Поэтому **на письме** мы ставим запятые, а **в устной речи** используем перечислительную интонацию. Получаются две разные цепочки:

(1) содержание – грамматика – уточнение грамматики – знак препинания;

(2) содержание – грамматика – уточнение грамматики – интонация;

Из них видно **истинное соотношение этих категорий**: семантика всегда главнее своей грамматической формы, знаки препинания уточняют грамматику, но при этом они **на равных соотносятся с интонацией.**

**3.  Можно ли правила ориентировать не на грамматику, а на интонацию**

Какой практический вывод из этого следует? Из прямого соответствия **знаков препинания и интонации** можно извлечь несомненную пользу.  Другими словами, правила пунктуации можно переписать иначе:  перечислить грамматические формы по всем темам, обозначить функцию уточнения для знаков препинания и соотнести знаки препинания с интонацией. Тогда выбор конкретного знака можно ориентировать на интонацию, а  **интонационный принцип прописать в правилах должным образом.**

Это будет выглядеть примерно так.  Однородные отношения между прилагательными следует отличать от неоднородных отношений по смыслу (далее перечисляются смысловые варианты). На письме однородные отношения при бессоюзной связи **обозначаются запятой,** а в устной речи для этого используется **перечислительная интонация**.

**4.  Для существующей Системы письма можно составить разные описания**

Получается, что всё зависит от Правил, которые **сейчас ориентированы  на грамматику**. Но ведь  надо отличать Систему письма от Правил, которые ее описывают,  – это же совсем не одно и то же! Систему не следует менять, но вот  Правила можно записать иначе. Тем более что они **не так уж и  хороши,** если по ним  за 11 лет нельзя научиться грамотно писать, а смысл в них ставится на второе место.

Да и так понятно, что можно написать вполне приемлемый текст и без справочника Розенталя, если вы постоянно общаетесь с письменными источниками. Мы выбираем знаки по интуиции, а она-то уж точно ближе к интонации, чем к  грамматическим правилам.

Вот такой неожиданный вывод можно сделать, сравнивая три принципа пунктуации.

**И вопросы:**

Какой принцип пунктуации вы считаете **главным?**

Нужна ли новая редакция Правил, где **интонации будет уделено достаточно внимания?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вкратце моё отношение к существующим правилам пунктуации (что на самом деле главенствует и что хотелось бы изменить).

1. Наши нынешние правила правильны ровно настолько, чтобы оправдывать ведущую роль **грамматического** принципа - такая сложилась циркулярная ситуация. "Препинания" на письме возникают и при отсутствии таковых в устной речи.
2. Грамматика сейчас при необходимости *считается с **семантикой*** (отсюда термины "тесная связь" и т. п.), зато ***интонацию** дискриминирует* почти полностью.

3-4. Что можно сделать: в случаях, когда диктуемая грамматикой пунктуация противоречит интонации, заведомо "лишние" запятые (наоборот не бывает) можно было бы сделать *факультативными* (мягкий вариант реформирования) или повелеть отбрасывать их (после чисто грамматической расстановки) по правилам (это сложнее организовать, поскольку не всегда интонация безальтернативна, и этому сложнее обучить). Пример грамматически мотивированной пунктуации, которая практически *всегда* противоречит интонации: **запятая после союза "и"**, возникающая в результате обособления последующего оборота, - пауза в этом месте возможна только в жанре тоста (когда "тостующий" вспоминает, что собирался сказать).

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за ответ, очень вы меня порадовали вашей прогрессивной позицией по отношению к правилам.  Я полагала, что все считают правила чем-то неприкосновенным и никакие значительные изменения не допускают.  Кстати, я вспомнила, что Правила 1956 года были оформлены иначе: там рассматривался каждый знак и указывалась область его применения. Как знать, может, еще вернемся к такому изложению, но на более высоком уровне.

Comment: Что касается несоответствия интонационного и грамматического принципов, то я объясняю это так. Несоответствие возможно в частных случаях. При постановке  интонационного тире  несоответствие только кажущееся. В действительности это авторское решение, и тире соответствует, к примеру,  желанию автора обособить (выделить) конструкцию или слово.

Comment: Отсутствие паузы после союза И при обособлении деепричастного оборота объясняется следующим образом: возможности интонации в большей степени ограничены, чем возможности графические.  Интонация выражает, например, отношения между простыми предложениями в составе сложного (две фонетические фразы), но при этом уже не может обозначить  обособление оборота (поэтому он включается во вторую фразу).