# Можно ли считать интонацию основным принципом в пунктуации?

Tags: грамматика, интонация

**Цитата:**   «Про интонационный принцип я не очень понял. Вы предлагаете подчинить правила этому принципу? Этот принцип, как вам известно, учитывается в русской пунктуации. Но он лишь **на третьем** месте».

Пожалуй, я уже могу сказать   со всей ответственностью: интонация – это совсем **не третий, а главный** принцип в пунктуации. И не только сказать, но и доказать это.

1.Интонация – это проявление невидимого мира **суперсегментных фонетических единиц**, к которым относятся слог, фонетическое слово, синтагма и фраза.

2.Но про слог слышали все, а вот **синтагмы и фразы** мы просто не замечаем. А они накладываются сверху на нашу речь, корректируя грамматическую форму и уточняя семантику. Не верите? А тогда зачем вы меняете **порядок слов** в предложении? Да, мы строим фразы таким образом, чтобы удобно было выделить ударением нужное слово.

3.А про **одноименные** члены предложения вы когда-нибудь слышали? Мне приходилось, да вот только не помню, когда и где.   Одноименными можно считать **грамматически однородные** члены, а вот по семантике они бывают однородными, неоднородными, уточняющими, пояснительными, присоединительными, обобщающими. И обозначить это  (при отсутствии союзов) можно только фонетическими средствами.

4.**Обособленные члены**?  Они или составляют отдельную фонетическую фразу, или уходят на второй план речи, что тоже обозначается интонацией. Интонация простого предложения меняется существенным образом, когда  обособляется какой-либо оборот.

5.В **бессоюзном сложном предложении** (БСП) интонации официально принадлежит ведущая роль, хотя об этом больше говорится, чем используется на практике. Можно знать три десятка правил, как выбрать знак  в БСП, но при этом затрудняться с пониманием, как в одном и том же предложении можно поставить запятую, тире или двоеточие (наглядный пример – это  недавний вопрос  про стихи). А вот интонация определит и выбор знака, и семантику, которую он обозначает.

6.Можно перечислить множество тем **с интонационным решением**: тире между подлежащим и сказуемым;  одиночный союз И, объединяющий в одну фразу однородные члены и однородные придаточные; повторяющийся союз И..И при тесном единстве, различение вводных слов и обстоятельств. **В любой теме,** где для одной и той же грамматической формы есть **варианты**, их различает только интонационная структура,  а вовсе не правила, которые вторичны по отношению к ней.

Я думаю, что примеров достаточно, а **вопрос** состоит в следующем.
Вы теперь **согласны** со мной, что интонация занимает первое, а не третье место  среди принципов пунктуации? А если не согласны, то можете это **доказать**?

Роль интонации обсуждалась:

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461689/Какой-принцип-в-пунктуации-является-основным](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461689/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC)

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461698/О-современных-планах-изменения-русского-правописания](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461698/%D0%9E-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 1):

Письмо  появляется на определенном этапе развития  речевой деятельности, а вот **интонирование текста** в устном варианте **существовало всегда.** Поэтому   знаки препинания не задают интонацию,  а  используются для записи реального звучания устной речи, как и нотные знаки в музыке.

Мне кажется, что эта простая мысль должна быть понятна и очевидна. **Грамматический строй языка**  обозначен в обоих вариантах, причем  даже п**ри отсутствии знаков препинания, которые появились не так уж давно**.

Но знаки пунктуации дали нам новые возможности. С их помощью  мы слышим нашу речь как бы **вживую**, со всеми смысловыми оттенками,   с выражением всех эмоций.

Итак, с помощью знаков препинания мы записываем  то, что уже **реально присутствует в нашей речи** и присутствовало всегда, но не наоборот.

Comment: Я тоже замечу, что это форум РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА, поэтому говорю я о роли интонации в русском яыке, но не в китайском языке и не в древних языках. Ваша информация, вероятно, может быть интересной и востребованной на других форумах. Здесь же мы обсуждаем постановку знаков препинания  в русских текстах и пользуемся официальными правилами Розенталя, который уделял интонации достаточно много внимания. Поэтому убедительная просьба к вам также учитывать (при ответе на вопросы) те правила, в которых Розенталь ссылается на интонационные особенности (например, термин "интонационное предупредждение").

Comment: Вы какую тему обсуждаете? Я говорю О ТРЕХ ПРИНЦИПАХ РУССКОЙ пунктуации и о том, что Розенталь уделял  интонационному принципу достаточно внимания. А вы о чем?  Про русский язык вообще? Это желательно на форуме обсуждать, а не лично со мной. Кроме того, я собираюсь вообще закрыть эту тему, поэтому спасибо за ваше внимание к моему вопросу. Кстати, « с каких пор» - это переводится  «“Since when?»

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, я надеюсь, что замечание про *супер* применительно к важности интонации шуточно, иначе выглядит нелепо. Пожалуй, стоит называть единицы, больше фонемы, *супрасегментными* во избежание подобных интерпретаций.

Во-вторых, утверждение про наше письмо как слоговое, кхм, как минимум неверно. Слоговое письмо – это когда единой графемой обозначается слог или подобная ему единица. В русском же графемой, буквой, обозначается фонема/звук. Вы сказали, что различаете твердые и мягкие слоги... и тут хочется спросить, что это и зачем это, потому что выглядит совершенно надуманным приемом.

В-третьих, чтобы основывать что-то на интонации, опишите свое предложение насчет того, как эту интонацию описывать. Классическая русистика довольно плоха в этом, если не включать туда работы Е. А. Брызгуновой.

В-четвертых, что значит «основана на интонации»? Так где ставить запятую/тире/etc.? Где происходит смена интонационного паттерна? В предложении

> Однако он не пришел.

в моем произнесении происходит резкая смена частоты основного тона после слов *однако* и *он*. Это значит, писать нужно так?

> Однако, он – не пришел?

Или

> Однако – он – не пришел?

Слишком много непонятного.

Comment: Ну, информация про слог я убираю, она здесь оказалась лишней (это философия в некотором роде).  Объясняю остальное. Я ориентируюсь на практику письма, а все работы по интонации к этой практике никакого отношения не имеют.  Русисты описывают РЕАЛЬНУЮ интонацию, и это их ОШИБКА, а при постановке знаков препинания нужно пользоваться МОДЕЛЯМИ,  где всего-то  два элемента: фразовое ударение как движение тона, которое и образует эту фразу, и паузы разной длительности.

Comment: Как использовать такие интонационные модели, я объясняю здесь уже четыре с половиной года, и все задачи решаю путем интонационного анализа,  но могу объяснить их и по правилам.  Поэтому примеров на форуме с моими решениями очень много. Да вот хотя бы возьмите последний вопрос (со стихами) или просто задайте предложение в вариативными знаками. Тогда я вам объясню, как пользоваться интонацией.  А то, что предлагают русисты, вероятно, интересно для декламации и выразительного чтения, но только не для письма.

Comment: ОднАко он // не пришЁл. Простое предложение. Здесь две фразы, восходящего и нисходящего тона. Пауза краткая, произносительная, не грамматическая. Обозначает перелом интонации, запятой не обозначается. Деление на две части соответствует делению на тему - рему, предмет - сообщение о предмете. Вот и весь анализ.

Comment: Послушайте, то, что вы описываете, не имеет отношения к интонации. Интонация — это то, что звучит, конкретная акустическая вещь. Вы — о чем-то другом. Надо оговаривать это заранее, а не апостериори. 

Если вам интересен мой взгляд — я считаю, что ваш прием не слишком нужен.

Comment: «Интона́ция — совокупность просодических характеристик предложения: тона (мелодики речи), громкости, темпа речи и её отдельных отрезков, ритмики, особенностей фонации».   Таким образом, интонацию понимают как комплексную характеристику, но главное в ней – это расстановка тонических ударений. В современных вузовских учебниках, особенно при изучении сложного предложения, указывается движение голоса на стыке отдельных частей, а также длительность пауз.

Comment: И когда я говорю об интонации и об интонационных моделях, то имею в виду именно это, а не что-то другое. Вы же считаете, что это лишнее. Тогда давайте попробуем сравнить две эти точки зрения. Вот, к примеру, мой вопрос  про оборот с «кроме». Никто на него не отвечает, и я полагаю, что без интонационного анализа там не обойтись. А вы не могли бы на него ответить?  Кстати,  интонационный принцип всё-таки признается, в правилах Розенталя интонация упоминается довольно часто, хотя и считается третьим номером.  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461789/Правило-обособления-оборота-с-кроме

Comment: @Sharon ответил по вашей просьбе на ваш вопрос. Что же до интонации, то проблема в том, что она не является предустановленным параметром, а может быть самая разнообразная; строить на ней пунктуацию — допускать огромную вариативность. Да, есть часто повторяющиеся паттерны — например, на стыке двух клауз (Когда я пришел [1], его не было [2]) кривая частоты основного тона обычно идет вверх — но использование таких паттернов сильно привязано к ситуации и к намерениям говорящего.

Comment: Составители новых учебников такой терминологией не пользуются, у них там все просто,например: двоеточие соответствует нисходяще-нисходящей интонации, увеличенная пауза с неполным понижением голоса. Вот вам характеристика знака, которой очень удобно пользоваться.   Всем рекомендую. У Розенталя говорится не так четко, но суть одна и та же.

Comment: Кстати, в своем ответе вы так и  не сделали вывод. Нужен ли в пунктуации интонационный принцип вообще, насколько он важен?

Comment: @Sharon я попросил бы давать ссылки на «новые учебники» и прочие работы, упоминаемые вами. Интонация иногда помогает верно расставить знаки препинания, это правда. «Вам всегда готов помочь». (Сказано без энтузиазма.) «Вам – всегда готов помочь!» (Сказано с рвением.)

Comment: "Вам всегда готов помочь". Здесь  неверный порядок слов в простом предложении, вот и получился их перечень на одной ноте. А во втором предложении  тире использовано для его деления  на две части: ВАм – всегдА готов помочь! Здесь задана расстановка ударений, выглядит нормально. Как видите, у  нас очень разные взгляды на интонацию и пунктуацию. Что касается ссылок, то я полагаю, они мне вряд ли  понадобятся. Я не предполагаю более на этом ресурсе писать что-либо подобное. Для тех,  кто разделяет мои взгляды, сказано  уже достаточно.