# Правило обособления оборота с "кроме"

Tags: пунктуация

У Розенталя допускается не обособлять оборот со значением включения, а оборот со значением выключения обособлять нужно. Но мне кажется, что такая регламентация лишняя. Рассмотрим предложение: "Все кроме лекаря чувствовали себя превосходно" (Б. Акунин). Здесь оборот со значением исключения не обособлен. Это ошибка? Можно как-то объяснить отсутствие обособления?
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=116#pp116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю вопрос. Вы сомневаетесь в пунктуации у Акунина?
Что не ошибка, это точно.

Во всяком случае - если следовать букве того, что написано у Розенталя.

> В зависимости от смысловой нагрузки, степени распространения оборота,
> близости к основной части предложения и т. д. могут обособляться
> (выделяться запятыми) существительные с предлогами или предложными
> сочетаниями кроме, вместо, помимо, сверх, за исключением, наряду с и
> др. (условно называемые дополнениями) с ограничительным или
> расширительным значением, т. е. ***включения, исключения,
> замещения***...
>
> ***Обособление или необособление таких оборотов факультативно:***

(Курсив - мой, b-s)

Я не помню контекста, но у Акунина этот оборот, судя по всему, не несет какой-то большой смысловой нагрузки и не является распространенным. Обособлять такой оборот совсем не хочется.

Что же касается "правила" о включительно-исключительном толковании оборота с "кроме" и подобных, то, насколько помню, оно не носит императивного характера и более напоминает некую запоминалку для корректоров. О чем недвусмысленно и говорит Розенталь.

(+)
Лопатин, правда, требует, пусть и не очень категорично, обособления в обоих случаях, но именно в обоих, не делая между ними различия. Быть судьей я тут не берусь, но что касакется правила о включении-исключении, то оно и Лопатиным отвергается в современном варианте пунктуации.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше ммнение.

Answer (score 0):

Если соблюдать рекомендацию, согласно которой обособляются обороты с *кроме* со значением исключения, то запятые здесь нужны, допущена пунктуационная ошибка.

Comment: "Все кроме лекаря чувствовали себя превосходно".  А зачем делить такое короткое предложение на три части, в чем смысл такой пунктуации? Следовать правилу, чтобы затемнить содержание и противоречить произношению? Вроде бы у пунктуации задачи ровно противоположные. И другой вопрос: а само правило на чем основано, что это за такой  оборот, которому приписаны особые полномочия?  Определить его значение можно и без запятых,  подставив синонимы "за исключением", "включая". К тому же обособление явно зависит от структуры, сравнить: Все чувствовали себя превосходно, кроме лекаря.

Comment: @Sharon хотите следовать правилам — следуйте; доверяете своим ощущениям и представлениям о целях пунктуации — доверяйте и не обособляйте, где не хочется. Проблема едва ли есть, не правда ли? 

Мне тоже не нравится ставить запятые в некоторых случаях. Например, в случае: «Конечно, нет» (в значении «нет»). Но вот надо ставить в обычном случае, не эмоциональном.

Comment: Я не писатель, а читатель. Вот книгу написал уважаемый и опытный автор, ее проверили редакторы и корректоры, а вы утверждаете, что там ошибка. У меня есть больше причин доверять им, чем вам. Если нет соответствия правилам, то можно сослаться на мнение  Розенталя об авторской пунктуации.