# Можно ли условно считать, что существуют мягкие и твердые слоги?

Tags: фонетика, слоги

Цитата: "Вы сказали, что различаете твердые и мягкие слоги... и тут хочется спросить, что это и зачем это, потому что выглядит совершенно надуманным приемом".

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461781/Можно-ли-считать-интонацию-основным-принципом-в-пунктуации/461784#461784](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461781/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/461784#461784)

Слог — это минимальная фонетико-фонологическая единица, характеризующаяся наибольшей акустико-артикуляционной слитностью своих компонентов, то есть входящих в него звуков. А еще слог — это минимальная суперсегментная единица.

И любой любознательный младший школьник может задать вопрос, который я задаю вам сейчас, причем его будет интересовать не история, а современное состояние языка.

К примеру, слоги ЛА и ЛЯ при аудиозаписи будут отличаться друг от друга. Мы  считаем, что согласный бывает твердым или  мягким, но ведь это условность. В действительности гласный тоже смягченный, над  ним при анализе даже ставят точку.

Поэтому с такой же степенью условности я могу считать, что существуют  "мягкие" и "твердые" слоги. И также условно могу считать гласный "твердым" или "мягким", а согласный одним и тем же  звуком.

Но мы так не делаем, **а вот почему?** Ведь так ближе к логике, потому что  для мягких согласных специальных букв нет, а для "мягких" гласных они есть.

Примечание. **Зачем я вообще говорю об этом?** Речь шла о важности слога как суперсегментной единицы. Ведь выбирая парные гласные, мы фактически обозначаем мягкость или твердость **всего слога,** а не только **согласного.**

---

ЭТО ОТВЕТ НА КОММЕНТАРИЙ (здесь говорится о том, можно ли иное  понимание  темы считать обязательно неправильным и некорректным).

**Два взгляда на науку**

Есть мнение, что не бывает **истины абсолютной**, и это очень верно. Всё современное развитие науки говорит о **виртуальности** нашего мира, о важнейшем значении **позиции наблюдателя**. Вот как выглядит фундаментальное понятие в современной физике:  электрон перестает быть вероятностной волной и становится частицей, если мы наблюдаем за ним. Из этого следует, что весь видимый  материальный мир – это результат нашего наблюдения.

И тогда о какой абсолютной истине можно вообще говорить?  Поэтому любые научные утверждения **верны в определенных пределах** – при заданных определениях и аксиомах, при определенной позиции наблюдателя, при непротиворечивости созданной таким образом системы научных взглядов.

Одно и то же явление может толковаться по-разному различными научными школами, но можно ли найти истину **за пределами этих школ**? Вероятно, по логике вещей, возможны и другие позиции для наблюдения.

Рассмотрим, к примеру, **фонетику и фонологию.** Фонема была открыта еще в начале прошлого века и обозначила важнейшее понимание **смысловой функции  звука**. Звук стал пониматься не только как физическое явление, но и как особый знак. Но это открытие  наука **"присвоила" себе полностью** – еще бы, какой простор для научной деятельности, какие сложные теории, сколько определений, одна гиперфонема чего стоит. Конечно, углубленное изучение предмета тоже необходимо, но вот простым пользователям в конечном счете **не досталось ничего** – что им делать с этой гиперфонемой, а также звуком, превратившимся в звукоряд?

Но ведь можно представить и другое понимание этой темы, более упрощенное, более ясное по сути, но **тоже истинное**. Надо только сменить наблюдателя, сделать наблюдателями **обычных носителей русской речи**, тем более что их большинство.  Объяснить сущность смыслового звука-знака можно и семилетнему ребенку.  Такое  понимание (в виде упрощенной модели)  можно использовать на практике при составлении **новых методик обучения**. Но ничего этого не делается.

**А слог?** Вот серия детских книжек «Читаем по слогам»; интересно,  по какой их научных теорий там обозначены слоги?

**Артикуляцию речи** в современных условиях можно изучить и без помощи лингвистов, а **физики** не хуже филологов понимают, что такое звук.  И как взаимодействуют согласные и гласные в составе слога они тоже могут понять без филологических терминов, а может, сделают  это и не хуже, чем филологи.

**И вывод.** Эпоха частного владения истиной  в рамках отдельной  науки заканчивается. Поэтому не стоит считать положения конкретной научной школы единственно правильными и абсолютно истинными.

**2. О пользе моделей**

Наука начинается, когда человек от описания явления переходит к его анализу, при этом  из всех  признаков выделяются  признаки существенные,   выдвигаются  определенные гипотезы, строятся практические модели.  Если эти модели работают, то  гипотеза признается верной теорией. Самые великие открытия  делались с помощью моделей,  на которых проверялась возможность **целенаправленного воздействия** человека на природу.

Если говорить **об интонации**, то можно считать, что это очень сложный комплекс, требующий всестороннего изучения. Но можно построить **модель**, выделив существенные признаки  (тоническое ударение,  движение тона, паузы различной длительности). И такая модель уже сейчас успешно применяется на практике.

3. **О публицистическом стиле речи**

Он особый, этот стиль. Его задача – не только раскрыть сущность явления, но и выразить отношение к нему, воздействовать на читателя.

Там рассматриваются и научные темы, но  **без специальной  сложной терминологии**. Публицистика в меньшей степени связана с научной точностью, она может использовать **упрощенные термины**, но при этом  старается изобразить суть вещей более ярко, понятно, образно.

Поэтому не стоит в этом случае считать текст  неверным, а автора – невежественным. Публицистический стиль – это способ донесения до широкой аудитории тех же  истинных знаний, но в более **проявленной и ясной форме.**

Comment: Если говорить о _всём слоге_, то к каким отнести слог "лань", если не вводить определение?

Comment: Я рассматриваю только слоги, состоящие из гласного и согласного, меня же графика интересует.    Давайте считать, что Ь обозначает редуцированный гласный, тогда  здесь два слога, а?

Comment: В конце моего ответа я цитирую два ваших высказывания и комментирую их. Но, пожалуй, не стоит больше обсуждать эту тему, как-то нет настроения. Спасибо вам...

Answer (score 1):

Что такое «смягченный гласный»? Акустически то, что называется мягким согласным, радикально отличается от того, что вы, возможно, называете «смягченным гласным».  В первом случае мы говорим либо о палатальности ([j]), либо о палатализации ([п']). Во втором... вероятно, вы имеете в виду ряд гласных, которые называются *передними*. Тем не менее это всё не имеет прямого отношения к слогу.

Переходя к вашему вопросу – потому что для русского языка понятие «твердых» и «мягких» слогов, как и слога в общем, не очень-то и нужно. Ознакомьтесь с тем, что отличает квантовые языки от волновых:

> Из сравнения фонотактической ситуации в разных языках мира следует вывод, что имеется два разных способа организации звукового потока, которые можно условно назвать "квантовый" и "волновой". Квантовая речь основана на соположении единиц со строго ограниченной структурой, их границы четко заданы. Волновая речь основана на чередовании вокалических вершин и консонантных провалов, границы нисходящего и восходящего склонов размыты.
> Языки типа русского и грузинского относятся к волновым, тогда как языки, которые мы рассматривали до них, являются квантовыми. Именно последние разумно называть слоговыми, однако нужно иметь в виду, что термин часто используется как синоним к "моносиллабический" и "морфосиллабический", т. е. для обозначения языков, в которых слог и морфема совпадают.

(Общая фонетика, С. В. Кодзасов и О. Ф. Кривнова)

Comment: Меня интересует акустика, физическое явление. Каждый гласный имеет свой частотный портрет. И вот гласный в слоге ЛЯ отличается по акустике от гласного в слове ЛА. Вы это будете отрицать? Вы скажете, что не отличается?

Comment: Отличается, конечно. И что это для вас значит?

Comment: Это значит,что не надо их считать одним и тем же звуком, как это в школе рассказывают деткам.  Какая артикуляция у согласного Л и у гласных, обозначаемых буквами А и Я. Гласный или согласный задает мягкость. Я думаю, что гласный.

Comment: Да, гласный задает, но сам при этом не изменяется.

Comment: Ну всё, на сегодня  белый флаг!   Завтра я с вами разберусь, может быть.

Comment: Так. В [л'а] и в [ла] разные и согласные, и гласные звуки. Фонемы же, однако, находятся в другом отношении: гласная фонема тут одна – /а/, согласные фонемы – разные. Так традиционно смотрят на русскую фонологию. Орфографически мягкость согласного обозначается буквой я, твердость согласного – а; эти буквы следуют за л. Качество гласного никак не обозначается, потому что это фонологически незначимо, а следовательно, не нужно. Вот и всё :) @Sharon

Comment: *..тогда как языки, которые мы рассматривали до них, являются квантовыми* - а какие языки они рассматривали "до них"?

Comment: @tum_ загляните в источник, если интересно. Для вопроса важен именно русский язык, а не те, которые «до них». К квантовым языкам можно отнести, например, английский.

Answer (score 0):

ЭТО РАСШИРЕННЫЙ КОММЕНТАРИЙ К ПОЛУЧЕННОМУ  ОТВЕТУ (здесь я  высказываю свое мнение о том, что слог хотя бы условно можно называть мягким или твердым в связи с тесным слиянием гласного и согласного внутри слога).

Цитата:

«Так **традиционно** смотрят на русскую фонологию».

Действительно,  больше ста лет уже смотрят, насмотреться не могут. А какие **практические результаты** от просмотра получены?  Почему о фонематической природе письма никто их простых пользователей не догадывается? Почему  правила, напрямую связанные с фонологией, объясняются на пальцах, даже употребление мягкого знака для обозначения мягкости  написано самым примитивным образом – заучить можно, а понять нельзя?  Не до нас, простых смертных, этим небожителям, изучающим «два разных способа организации звукового потока, которые можно условно назвать квантовым и волновым»

А у меня вот **нетрадиционная ориентация** (в части фонологии и прочих наук). Пересказывать чужие мысли я не люблю, но непременно учитываю позитивное содержание всей информации по интересующим меня темам. И на эту проблему у меня примерно такой взгляд.

1. Существует закон **слогового сингармонизма**. Согласный и гласный в слоге сближаются по своей артикуляции, то есть получаются два варианта произношения – условно мягкий и условно твердый слог.
2. Но какой звук, гласный или согласный, задает палатализованный (мягкий) вариант слога, кто из них **ведущий, а кто ведомый?**
3. Вы можете произнести мягкие варианты гласных  А, О, У, Э **отдельно**, без согласных? Да, немного непривычно, но вполне возможно.   А вы можете произнести мягкие согласные без  гласного? Нет, гласный призвук будет всегда присутствовать.
4. Что из этого следует?  **Согласный** – это всего лишь шум, образующийся, когда воздух преодолевает препятствие, созданное, к примеру, кончиком языка и нёбом.  Это собственная природа согласного звука.

**Гласный** – это гармоничные колебания воздуха, созданные голосовыми связками и усиленные в полости рта, выступающего как резонатор. От положения языка зависит качество гласного.

5. Поэтому **гласный задает палатализацию слога**, так как  изменяется артикуляция гласных –  язык при произношении   звуков А, О, У, Э **сдвигается вперед и вверх** по сравнению с их обычной позицией, характерной для твердого слога.  Таким образом, сначала **подготавливается** позиция языка, нужная для произношения мягкой пары.
6. А вот мягкий **согласный**  только соответствует этому положению. У мягкого  согласного  появляются два места образования: (1) его собственное положение кончика языка и  (2) заданное гласным поднятие спинки языка к небу.

Поэтому мы видим **единый слог**, где сложно отделить мягкий согласный от смягченного варианта гласного. И этот единый слог называется суперсегментной единицей.

7. Вот и неудивительно, что «мягкий слог»  обычно определяется по **гласным буквам**, именно так детей учат читать – в детской азбуке вы увидите такие парные слоги. Хотя вот утверждается следующее:  «Вы сказали, что различаете твердые и мягкие слоги... и тут хочется спросить, **что это и зачем это,** потому что выглядит совершенно **надуманным** приемом».

**Еще цитаты** из обсуждения:

1. – Да, гласный задает (мягкость), но сам при этом **не изменяется**. Первоначальное обманчивое восприятие разницы исходит от согласного.

– Нет, меняется гласный,  положение языка сдвигается вперед и вверх. Гласному при разборе  даже ставят одну или  две точки в словах: хотя, пять.

2. – Гласный звук **не может быть** твердым или мягким. Парные гласные буквы определяют мягкость/твердость предшествующего согласного. Как музыкант, я не слышу разницы между гласными в слогах ЛА - Л-а-а-а-а-а и ЛЯ - Л'-а-а-а-а-а. Так же и буквы А и Я: А состоит из одного звука, Я – из двух, один из которых тот же А.

– Я вас поняла. Это сначала произносится «смягченный гласный», но если музыкант будет  тянуть его пять минут, то он точно перейдет в обычный твердый гласный.

Comment: Sharon, в вашем ответе допущены решительно некорректные утверждения. 1. «Почему о фонематической природе письма никто их простых пользователей не догадывается?» – потому что это не нужно простым пользователям. Орфографические правила работают без ссылок на МФШ. 2. «Существует закон слогового сингармонизма». Вы неверно понимаете, что это такое. Скорее всего, вы взяли этот термин из палеославистики. Во-первых, это __фонологический__ принцип, а не фонетический; во-вторых, суть его не в «сближении», а просто в том, что в пределах слога возможны лишь сочетания непалат. согл. + непередн. гл. и наоб.

Comment: 3. «ведущий, а кто ведомый». Почитайте о явлении коартикуляции. Всё довольно прозаично: если вы произносите палатализованный согласный, то следующий непередний гласный вынужден стать более передним, так как язык не может перемещаться во рту моментально. 4. «Нет, гласный призвук будет всегда присутствовать» -- это демагогия, не имеющая отношения к тому, о чем вы говорите. Произнося изолированный гласный, вы делаете, почти наверняка, гортанную смычку в начале. И что? (то есть произносите [ʔa̙], etc.)

Comment: 5. «Согласный – это всего лишь шум». Существует группа сонорных согласных, выделяемых по акустическим признакам. Так вот, у сонорных в большинстве случаев заметного шума нет. (Ладефогед, например, вообще предпочитает говорить об отсутствии шума.) Жаль, что вы так упрощаете. 6. «усиленные в полости рта, выступающего как резонатор» А носовая полость? А глотка?.. Опять упрощение. 7.  «От положения языка зависит качество гласного». А мягкое нёбо? А опущенная челюсть? А растянутые/вытянутые губы? А тип фонации (положение связок)?

Comment: 8. «сравнению с их обычной позицией, характерной для твердого слога». Что дает вам основания считать «обычной» позицией «твердый слог»? Вы осознаете, что «твердый слог» в русском языке – это слог с веляризованным или велярным согласным, то есть гласный испытывает влияние доп. артикуляции согласного так же, как и в случае с палатализованным/палатальным согласным? В вашем любимом слоге ЛА гласный [а] отодвинут назад в сравнении с изолированным вариантом, потому что [л] – веляризованный согласный.

Comment: «Не до нас, простых смертных, этим небожителям, изучающим "два разных способа организации звукового потока, которые можно условно назвать квантовым и волновым"». Печально видеть, что для вас труд поколений лингвистов – это ничто и вы не хотите узнать, какие результаты были достигнуты, прежде чем выдвигать свои, безусловно более верные и всеобъемлющие объяснения... Еще печальнее видеть ваше заигрывание («нас, простых смертных», «этим небожителям»), которое отдает популизмом, что никогда не было хорошо для научной деятельности.

Comment: Спасибо вам за потраченное время и за минусовку тоже в качестве дополнительного аргумента. У нас такие разные взгляды на всё, что обсуждать сказанное не имеет смысла.  Но один вопрос всё-таки вам задан. Если вы так хорошо разбираетесь в лингвистике, то почему так мало отвечаете на вопросы, не несете нам свет своих знаний. Вот бы где проверить истинность ваших суждений.

Comment: Я хотела задать вам еще один вопрос  по практической интонации, но теперь раздумала. Ваш ответ про оборот с"кроме" меня не удовлетворил, другие его тоже не поддержали. А практика - это мера истины. Можно придумывать сколько угодно теорий, но если они не работаю на благо человека, то кому они нужны? С большим уважением и еще раз спасибо за беседу.

Comment: Вот интересный вопрос про кошку https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461794/Запятая-между-сказуемыми-Сложное-предложение  Решения разные, разве не интересно выступить со своей точкой зрения. Присоединяйтесь! Нам всегда интересно ваше мнение.

Comment: скачайте приложение Яндекса, поговорите с Алисой – как думаете, плохо поработали фонетисты и речевые инженеры, плохие «теории» (с которыми, вы, вероятно, не знакомые, но о которых судите с видом компетентности) придумали, раз такое возможно? Практика – мера истины... Ну да, ну да... скажите это специалистам по теоретической физике, философии, истории, теоретической лингвистике, социологии, etc.