# Запятая между сказуемыми. Сложное предложение

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, сказуемые, сложное-предложение, и

**Проверять любимую кошку до того как покинуть дом, вошло в привычку и происходило автоматически.**
Нужна ли запятая? Проверять кошку вошло в привычку **и** происходило автоматически — запятая будто не нужна. Или перед "происходило" нужно поставить только... Или тот вариант, который в начале вопроса?

Answer (score 3):

Да, это однородные сказуемые, соединённые неповторяющимся союзом *и*, поэтому никакой запятой стоять не должно, вы абсолютно правы.

Но у вас не поставлена запятая после слова *того*, а она здесь необходима: это сложное предложение, а его части разделяются запятыми.

***Проверять любимую кошку до того, как покинуть дом, вошло в привычку и происходило автоматически.***

Answer (score 3):

Конечно же, запятая перед союзом "и" не нужна — он соединяет однородные сказуемые.
А вот где поставить запятую перед придаточным предложением, расчленять ли составной подчинительный союз [**до того(,) как**](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=176) — это, как мне думается, основной вопрос.

Вот что пишет Розенталь ([§ 34. Запятая при сложных подчинительных союзах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138,5#pp138)).
Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения соединена с главной с помощью сложного (составного) подчинительного союза, то запятая ставится один раз:

1. **перед союзом,** если придаточная часть следует за главной или находится внутри нее:
   *…Потоптались на месте и решили, **перед тем как зайдёт солнце**, опять собраться* (Сер.).

Это как раз о нашем предложении (придаточное — внутри). Я бы поставила знаки так:
*Проверять любимую кошку, **до того как** покинуть дом, вошло в привычку и происходило автоматически.*

(Если расчленить союз "до того как" и изъять придаточное, то получится такое предложение:
Проверять любимую кошку до того вошло в привычку и происходило автоматически.
Не думаю, что предложение имеет корректный смысл.)

Comment: Разае это однородные сказуемые, а не два односоставных неопределëнно-личных предложения? Запятой всë равно не надо, но интересно, какое правило применять.

Comment: Не думаю, что это неопределенно-личные предложения. Вот они: _За стеной поют. В дверь постучали. ...слышно было, как там спешили, как стучали ножами, как хлопали дверью на блоке._ http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 2):

*Проверять любимую кошку до того, **как покинуть дом**, вошло в привычку и происходило автоматически.*

Прежде всего надо понять смысл сказанного. Попробуем упростить предложение: ***Проверка** (кого?) **любимой кошки** (когда?) **перед уходом из дома** вошла в привычку и происходила автоматически.*

В заданном предложении этот смысл нужно сохранить. Вместо существительного использован инфинитив, а сказуемое с ним сочетается в форме ср.рода. Поэтому здесь у нас те же однородные сказуемые — *вошло и происходило*. Инфинитив в роли подлежащего в двусоставном предложении.

А вот "время проверки" обособлять  не следует, поэтому **местоименную часть** временного союза оставляем в составе главного предложения.

В итоге получаем: *Проверять любимую кошку до того, **как покинуть дом,** вошло в привычку и происходило автоматически.*

Ну точно, как  в ответе у Игоря. Но я за него уже проголосовала раньше.

Comment: Так ведь (когда?) **перед уходом из дома** и есть по значению (когда?) **до того как покинуть дом**. А Вы это значение разделили. У Вас получается: Проверка (кого?) любимой кошки (когда?) **перед** вошла в привычку и происходила автоматически.

Comment: Нет, Римма, я полагаю, что разделили именно вы, используя ВСТАВОЧНУЮ конструкцию. У меня же местоименная часть вошла в главное предложение и на нее падает ударение. Проверить кошку нужно до определенного МОМЕНТА (до того), а потом в придаточном раскрывается содержание этого момента.

Comment: "Моё" предложение можно перестроить без потери смысла, а "Ваше" — нет. Сравните: "у меня" — _Проверять любимую кошку вошло в привычку и происходило автоматически  — до того как покинуть дом_; "у Вас" — _Проверять любимую кошку до того вошло в привычку и происходило автоматически — как покинуть дом._ (Вместо тире можно поставить и запятую — все равно смысл потерян.)

Comment: Что я могу еще сказать? Никогда не подменяйте одну грамматическую форму другой, это абсолютно некорректно. У каждой формы свое значение, не надо этих экспериментов.  Определяйте смысл заданной грамматической формы, работайте с ней.  Если придаточное полностью обособить, то оно из основного сообщения переходит в добавочное, то есть  мы НЕ СООБЩАЕМ в основном тексте, в каком случае мы эту кошку проверяем. А мы должны это ПОДЧЕРКНУТЬ.  И общее положение: значимость придаточного возрастает, если мы делаем ударение на местоименной части союза.

Answer (score 2):

Во втором ответе я хочу высказаться более определенно по поводу обособления придаточного, ссылаясь на Розенталя и учебники по грамматике.

**1.  Розенталь**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

Из Розенталя я приведу  его высказывание о том,  **когда  расчленяется союз**:
В зависимости от смысла и интонации, логического подчеркивания придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, наличия в предложении определенных лексических элементов и других условий сложный союз может расчленяться на две части.

Также приведу два его примера по этой теме.

(1)  *Дедушка приказал не будить Татьяну **до тех пор, пока** сама не проснётся* (Акс.);

(2) *Потоптались на месте и решили, **перед тем как** зайдёт солнце, опять собраться* (Сер.);

В первом примере местоименная часть союза входит в состав главного предложения (основного сообщения)  и выделена **логическим ударением**. Это важно, так как **точно указано**, до каких пор нельзя будить Татьяну.

Во втором примере  участники решили собраться – это главное сообщение, а придаточное  только **уточняет время**, это дополнительная информация.

**2. Из учебника по современному синтаксису**

Позиция придаточных является **структурным элементом**, и ее изменение приводит к модификации грамматического значения сложноподчиненного  предложения.
**При  интерпозиции** придаточная часть имеет оттенок **добавочного** сообщения и приближается к **вводно-вставочным** конструкциям.

3. Соответственно, я делают вывод, что обособление придаточного  в приведенном предложении является **ошибочным** или по крайней мере **нежелательным.**

*Проверять любимую кошку **до того, как** покинуть дом, вошло в привычку и происходило автоматически.*

В основном сообщении указывается, когда проверяется «наличие кошки», это **основной смысл**, но никак не добавочный. Ударение падает на местоименную часть союза, содержание местоимения раскрывает придаточное.